# How can I get rid of the NetworkManager applet if I use wicd?

Tags: debian, networkmanager, cinnamon, wicd, devuan

I'm running Cinnamon on a Devuan GNU/Linux 3 (Beowulf) machine - which is essentially the same as Debian 10 (Buster).

My distribution uses the wicd daemon for network connection management; and I have an applet on my panel. But - an applet for NetworkManager is also present, even though I don't need it. I tried to get rid of it, but couldn't figure out how. Haven't found where its presence is configured, and it also doesn't seem to be its own separate process which I could avoid having run.

What can I do to get rid of the applet?

[image]

<sub>**Don't want:** NetworkManager, The applet to the right of the "US".
**Want to keep:** wicd, The applet to the left of the clock.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Solutions as presented by [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cinnamon#Disable_the_NetworkManager_applet) - this is a mere recitation.

---

In short the nm-applet package cannot be removed as it is essential part of cinnamon but you can suppress loading it by creating a custom cinnamon configuration.

```
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop ~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

And append the line

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

---

Alternatively block it by overriding the command itself:

```
ln -s /bin/true /usr/local/bin/nm-applet
```

Notably `usr/local/bin` of course must precede the standard location of `nm-applet` in the `PATH` in this case.

Comment: The link suggestion depends on your path seeing `/usr/local/bin` before the actual applet executable and might be prone to error.

Comment: I agree, but it should be common practice to put local and user-defined settings so that they override global/system-wide/default settings. Otherwise the whole idea of adjusting systems to user preferences and local needs would be corrupted.

Comment: `Hidden=true` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just disable the network-manager service if you rely on `wicd`, and simply disable the autostart of `nm-applet` with:

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service 
$ sudo echo "Hidden=true" >> /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

You can also check your autostart configuration for .desktop files with `dex` in dry mode (you may need to `sudo apt install dex` first)

```bsh
$ dex -ad 

...
Executing command: gsettings-data-convert
Executing command: light-locker --late-locking
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-a11y-settings
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-datetime
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gsd-disk-utility-notify
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-print-notifications
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-screensaver-proxy
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sharing
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-smartcard
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-wacom
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-wwan
Executing command: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
...
```

Unless you are proficient in configuring your wifi connection - including edits to the `wpa_supplicant.conf` for key-mgmt - from the terminal, you should definitely not mess with the network-manager's GUI wrapper `nm-applet` executable itself in `/usr` , because if for some reason your installation of `wicd` happens to break (user-error, accidentally, bug in an update etc.) you will still have all of your `network-manager` package files, including `nm-applet` GUI as a fallback, allowing you to `apt update && apt [install/upgrade/full-upgrade]`

Comment: The service _is_ disabled. I'll try your suggestion regarding the use of `Hidden`.

Comment: One other important point: while `systemctl disable network-manager.service` disables the service (removes its symlinks hence no automatic start at boot) it does not prevent the `network-manager.service` from being reactivated either manually or by some system process with appropriate permissions. If you rely on `wicd` completely, you may want to `systemctl mask network-manager.service` instead which both disables and hides the service preventing any type of start while it is masked.

Comment: `systemctl`? Is that a systemd thing? I don't use that abomination, thank you very much - and neither should you! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused now because you stated that your system is essentially a Debian 10 in the first post. What is your service manager then if you do not use `systemd`

Comment: [Devuan](http://www.devuan.org/) is Debian without systemd. You can use sysvinit, openrc and maybe upstart.